# outlook2016 VBA rule run script error 'The script "" doesn't exist or is invalid'

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

as in title, i tried to run my script with a rule in outlook
the program worked find on its own but once i linked it with a rule it keeps showing this error, what's wrong?
i've tried evrything i could, re opening outlook, reset rules etcetc but it's still not working.
it always just shows 'The script "" doesn't exist or is invalid'.
here is my code below

```vb
Sub FolderCreation(oLookMail As Outlook.MailItem)

Const tFFolderPath As String = "R:\xxxxxxx"
Dim oLookItem As Object
Dim oLookFldr As Folder
Dim folderObj, newFldr As Outlook.Folder
Dim oLookName As NameSpace
Dim yearStr, dummyFolderName, tFSubFolderPath As String
Dim Quarter
mailDate = oLookMail.ReceivedTime
Quarter = CStr((Month(mailDate) + 2) \ 3)
yearStr = CStr(year(mailsDate))
dummyFolderName = yearStr & "Q" & Quarter
trailerFeeSubFolderPath = tFFolderPath & yearStr & "Q" & Quarter
Debug.Print dummyFolderName

'Create Folder On Drive
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not .FolderExists(tFSubFolderPath) Then .CreateFolder tFSubFolderPath
End With

'Setup
Set oLookName = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oLookFldr = oLookName.Folders("xxxxxxxx@outlook.com")

'Create Folder in Outlook
existvalue = False
For Each folderObj In oLookFldr.Folders
    If folderObj.Name = "XYXY" Then existvalue = True
    Next
If existvalue = False Then
    Set newFldr = oLookFldr.Folders.Add("XYXY")
End If

Set oLookFldr = oLookName.Folders("xxxxxxxx@outlook.com").Folders("XYXY")

'Create Subfolder under XYXY
existvalue = False
For Each folderObj In oLookFldr.Folders
    If folderObj.Name = dummyFolderName Then existvalue = True
    Next
If existvalue = False Then
    Set newFldr = oLookFldr.Folders.Add(dummyFolderName)
End If

'Create Folder in Drive (public function that works)
CreateFHFolders (dummyFolderName)
Dim kwFull As String
Dim keyWord() As String
kwFull = "aaa,bbb,ccc"
keyWord = Split(kwFull, ",")
Dim fHName As String
Dim saveAttPath As String
Dim fileName As String
If oLookMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    For Each kw In keyWord
        If InStr(oLookMail.Subject, kw) > 0 Then
            Select Case kw
            'Mapping
            Case "aaa"
                fHName = "KKK"
            Case "bbb"
                fHName = "HHH"
            Case "ccc"
                fHName = "JJJ"
            End Select
            saveAttPath = tFFolderPath & dummyFolderName & "\" & fHName & "\"
            For Each Att In oLookMail.Attachments
                fileName = Att.fileName
                Att.SaveAsFile saveAttPath & fileName
            Next
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

it is a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare the sub as public in the following way:

```
Public Sub FolderCreation(oLookMail As Outlook.MailItem)
```

If it doesn't work you need to place the VBA macro to the `ThisOutlookSession` module to be discoverable.

Read more about that in the [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) article.